# Can you force sets of rows to be unique?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, constraint

Let's say we have a table like this with a primary key of (nr, key):

```
nr | key | val
---|-----|------
1  | 1   | a
2  | 1   | a
2  | 2   | b
3  | 1   | a
3  | 2   | c
```

Every set of rows (grouped by `nr` column) is supposed to be unique, as is the value of the `key` column *within each of those groups*. Additionally, no group may consist of *rows* with the exact same values for [`key`,`val`].

So inserting a row of `VALUES (4,1,'a')` or the group `VALUES (4,1,'a'),(4,2,'b')` would be invalid, because the former would duplicate the row with `nr=1` and the latter the `nr=2` grouping.

Is it possible to enforce that purely on the database? The only way I can think of is to use a procedure, but that still wouldn't stop anyone from inserting invalid rows manually, would it? Also, if you delete the row (2,2), then the `nr=1` row would suddenly be duplicated by the group with `nr=2`.

Or am I going about this all wrong? I'm basically trying to group multiple sets of `key=>value` rows.

The unique constraint is basically `GROUP_CONCAT(key,val)` with a `GROUP BY nr`. But I don't see a way to express that in the schema. A change of DB is not out of question. I've looked into [PostgreSQL partial indices](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html), but they don't seem to help here, do they?

Comment: Use Triggers to enforce this constraint. This should stop someone trying to delete/update/insert incorrect data manually by someone. However, one can always disable the triggers, if he knows about them and has privileges to do so.

Comment: What is your MySQL / MariaDB version ? Also, can you explain a bit more about the business logic here ? Maybe there is a better way to achieve the requirements in a different schema.

Comment: What would that trigger look like? It'd have to do a select on the whole table first, wouldn't it? Doesn't sound great.

Comment: Yeah. Maybe denormalize the schema, and store all the rows for an `nr` group in a `JSON`. In that case, you can apply UNIQUE constraint on the json field itself. Also, new versions of MySQL can index JSON data, so you can minimize performance loss due to denormalization